# Infinite loading with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, loops, font-size

I'm making a responsive slider and on some resolution my text doe not fit my slide.

I want to reduce the font size in that case but I'd like it to reduce only when necessary.

I've made the following code but the page is loading for ever ... Would you have any idea what the problem is ?

Thank you 
(The goal is that .desktop-slider-container height is always smaller than

```js
 $('.desktop-slider-item').each(function(){
        var img = $(this).children('.desktop-slider-img');
        var cont = $(this).find('.desktop-slider-container');
        var mult = 1;
        if(cont.height() > img.height()){
            while(cont.height() > img.height() - 50){
                mult = mult - 0.05
                cont.find('.desktop-slider-name').css('font-size',toString(4*mult)+'rem');
                cont.find('.desktop-slider-role').css('font-size',toString(1.25*mult)+'rem');
                cont.find('.desktop-slider-name').css('font-size',toString(1*mult)+'rem');
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desktop-slider-item">
    <div class="desktop-slider-body">
        <div class="desktop-slider-container">
            <h2 class="desktop-slider-name">
                <span>SomeText</span>
                <span>Some Text</span>
            </h2>
            <div class="desktop-slider-role">Some Text</div>
                <a href="sometext" class="desktop-slider-link">Some text
                    <span class="right_arrow" style="background-image:url('../images/next_arrow.png');"> </span>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="desktop-slider-img">
            <img src="sometext" alt="">
            <div class="desktop-slider-date">
                <span class="day">09</span>
                <span class="mounth">avril</span>
                <span class="year">2019</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show also html please